# How do I create a macro that will run a formula loan by loan, and paste the output in a separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a pricing model and am wondering how I am able to get the macro to run the pricing loan by loan and have the output pasted in a separate tab (this would also be loan by loan, so it cannot overwrite). I used the macro recorder and this is what I have so far, but I'm a novice and not sure how to loop this until it hits a blank cell (I did the first two loans....)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Cashflows").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Cashflows").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The tools you need:

To figure out the last row:

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'This simulates selecting the last cell in "A" Column,
    'hitting "End" and "Up Arrow", then returns that row number
    'as in integer.
```

To cycle through each row:

```
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To 10 '(Or replace "10" with "LastRow")
        'Do something like look at a range value:
        Debug.Print Cells(I, 1).Value
    Next I
```

Finally, this is going to be a lot easier if you use `.value = .value` instead of copying and pasting:

```
    Dim RowNum As Integer
    RowNum = 10
    
    Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value   'Copies Value from B1 into A1
    Cells(1, 1).Value = Range("B1").Value   'Does Exact same thing as above: Cells(row, column)
        'Copy A10:C10 from sheet2 to sheet1:
    Sheet1.Range("A" & RowNum & ":C" & RowNum).Value = Sheet2.Range("A" & RowNum & ":C" & RowNum)
```

See how far you get with that and come back if you have more specific questions.
There are lots of good resources out there if you're having trouble.

Comment: This is what I've changed to but I can't figure out how to loop it. Ideally it'd run down all the loans in the input tab, put them into the cashflow tab (where I'm calculating price) and then dump into Output

```

Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Sheets("Input").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To LastRow

Sheets("Cashflows").Range("A3").Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A2")

Sheets("Cashflows").Range("A3:U3").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Output").Range("A2:U2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next i


End Sub

Comment: @amcook1989 Post some example images of the sheets you're working with. It's good you have all your data transfers inside your `For` loop, now you need to change the `Range()` references to use the value of `I` to select different rows as `I` increments. For example, If `LastRow` = 10, it will iterate 10 times ( `I =1 to LastRow` ). Using `Range("A" & I).value` will return Cell "A1" value first iteration, "A2" value the second iteration... and so on. Finally, you need to replace Your copy paste with a direct value change like we did before.